# What is the name of a UI element containing social media sharing buttons?

Tags: gui-design

In the following link there is an element that has a facebook, twitter and youtube buttons, I would like to know how it's called and if there is a plugin that has it.

[image]

Comment: There are lots of services that provide social media integration. [Try the googles.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=social+share+buttons)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a dedicated name but people call it social sidebar / social bar / social media icons.

There are many pens available online which can be used directly with or without modifications:

[Example 1](https://codepen.io/anandvip/pen/ELuKd%20)

[Example 2](https://codepen.io/vpdemo/pen/gbvprR%20)

Just take a look and google "social sidebar codepen" you will get many options.

I hope this'll help you :)

Comment: Your links 404 for me.

Comment: @PixelSnader now they will work fine. Mistakenly added option text along with the copied link. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are Social Media Buttons or Social Sharing buttons. I would call the elements in this specific example "Expanding Social Sharing Buttons".